# White on black without inverting colors?

Tags: macos

When using Mac OS X, is there a way to have white text on black background without inverting the other colors?

Comment: For all applications?

Comment: Yes, for all applications.

Answer (score 13):

### Create a Custom ICC Profile

Theoretically this is possible by creating a custom [ICC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICC_profile) profile for your monitor. However, creating an ICC profile is not trivial.

You can see this ability by looking at some of the specialised profiles in `/Library/ColorSync/Profiles/`. The Gray Tone profile for example compresses all the colours into a single black to white strip.
[image: Gray Tone ICC profile]

The Lightness Increase profile's 3D representation demonstrates how any colour can be mapped to any other colour.
[image: Lightness Increase ICC profile]

There are a number of problems to this approach. Mac OS X's text is [anti-aliased](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_anti-aliasing). Inverting just black with white will likely result in outlined text; the gray pixels surrounding each letter will not be inverted.

### An Alterative Approach: Editing System.clr

An alternative approach is to alter the colours returned by Apple's [NSColor](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class. This class provides the colours and patterns used across Mac OS X. The file that stores the Developer colours is located at `/System/Library/Colors/System.clr`.

Looking at Apple's [Color Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DrawColor/Concepts/AboutColorLists.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000757-BAJHJEDI) guide, I suspect a developer may be able to load the file into a NSColorList instance, alter the colour, and write back the file.

This goes against Apple's advice not to alter files in `/System`, but it is probably your best solution. The modification task requires someone with Objective-C knowledge and available consulting time.

Comment: Good answer @Graham-Miln, could you elaborate on it?

Comment: @Griffo what would like to know more about?

Comment: Hey @GrahamMiln thank you so much for the answer. I am figuring out how to create an ICC profile, but I don't know how to apply it. Any ideas here?

Comment: turning off "font smoothing" (anti aliasing) is pretty easy. Just search "font" in system preferences or go to general, it should be at the bottom in general. 

When I have time I am going to try editing .icc profiles in the ColorSync folders. In system preferences> display>colors, you can "Calibrate..." to create a sort of default icc profile in ~/Library/ColorSync/Profiles/what-you-named-it.icc. 

What I cannot figure out is how to directly edit the color profile (.icc) in photoshop..

Comment: @DevinGRhode consider [asking a new question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) about how to easily [edit ICC profiles](http://color.org/profilingtools.xalter) on macOS.

Answer (score 1):

You could turn on both color inverting and grayscale mode in Accessibility preferences - that would give you white-on-black without weird inverted colors, but everything would be grayscale.