# How to invert screen colors and color hue?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, color, accessibility

I want to "smart invert" my colors like this app does: http://arcanesanctum.net/negativescreen/

I tried the app called "Nocturne 2.0.0" but its "Invert Hue" option has no effect because of this issue: https://code.google.com/p/blacktree-nocturne/issues/detail?id=63

Is there a way to do this?

I am using Mavericks 10.9.2 on MBP2011

Answer (score 1):

If you can create or find an appropriatey inverted [ICC profile](http://www.color.org/iccprofile.xalter), this can be used to invert your colours.

[image: Display colour profile]

See [White on black without inverting colors?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/8374/white-on-black-without-inverting-colors?rq=1) for more about how the display's colours can be manipulated.